# Android - EditText overlap with Softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an Activity which have some EditText. When I click/touch on EditText softkeyboard appear. But the EditTexts which are at bottom of the screen, overlap with softkeyboard. Upper half of the EditText is shown and lower half is under the keyboard.

I set the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Any Suggestion about how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

For me i did not want to assume that keyboards heights are a certain measurement.  Whatever view your concerned about make a onTouchListener and then do this:

```
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()  {



        Runnable shifter=new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    int[] loc = new int[2];                 
                    //get the location of someview which gets stored in loc array
                    findViewById(R.id.someview).getLocationInWindow(loc);
                    //shift so user can see someview
                    myscrollView.scrollTo(loc[0], loc[1]);   
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }}
        };

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        View divider=findViewById(R.id.someview);
        myscollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if (!divider.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds))  {
            // the divider view is NOT  within the visible scroll window thus we need to scroll a bit.
            myscollView.postDelayed(shifter, 500);
        }



    });
```

//essentially we make a runnable that scrolls to a new location of some view that you WANT visible on the screen.  you execute that runnable only if its not within the scrollviews bounds (its not on the screen).  This way it shifts the scrollview to the referenced view (in my case 'someview' which was a line divider).