# Properly Scrolling an EditText into view when focused

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I've got an EditText, which is ultimately inside of a ScrollView. I've implemented a comment feature which takes you to a new activity, and automatically places focus in the edit text so that the user can immediately start writing his comment.

Unfortunately, it doesn't quite scroll the edittext into view, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: Improper Scrolling]

I would like to see something more like this, where the EditText comes completely into view (see below). I already looked at the [`android:WindowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft), and it seems like the default values should work ... and indeed, it does mostly work because it does scroll, just not enough.

[image: What I'd like to see]

So is there anything I can do to get the desired behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

is your min SDK 3? 
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209887/android-edittext-overlap-with-softkeyboard)

Hope you have tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" and check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html).

I would give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000795/android-keyboared-overlaps-with-the-edittext-with-printscreens) a go.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try to programatically use this on the **onCreate()** method of you activity.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

"**SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN**" adjustment option is set to have a window pan when an input method is shown, so it doesn't need to deal with resizing but just panned by the framework to ensure the current input focus is visible.